# Semantic Ui React - SideBar Top

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I am using SideBar component from Semantic Ui React, I just copy-paste the sideBar example but the sidebar has a top property set to 0 that is causing that my sidebar is on my header, I did a google inspect and I find the property to change but how can I do that with custom CSS ? which selectors I need to use?

Here is my SideBar.js with the code from semantic

```
const SidebarExampleSidebar = () => {


return (

        <Sidebar
            as={Menu}
            animation='overlay'
            icon='labeled'
            inverted
            vertical
            visible='true'
            width='thin'
        >
            <Menu.Item as='a'>
                <Icon name='home' />
                Home
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item as='a'>
                <Icon name='gamepad' />
                Games
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item as='a'>
                <Icon name='camera' />
                Channels
            </Menu.Item>
        </Sidebar>


 )
}
export default SidebarExampleSidebar
```

Dashboard.js

```
class Dashboard extends Component {


render() {

    return (
        <div>
            <SidebarExampleSidebar/>
        </div>
    );
 }
}
export default Dashboard;
```

App.js

```
class App extends Component {

 render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Header/>
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
        <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
        <Route exact path="/users" component={UsersLayout} />
        <Route path="/surveys/new" component={SurveyNew} />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
 }
}
export default App;
```

You can see here the render and google inspect[image: Goolge inspect and render]

Comment: The Sidebar will take all the height of its parent, not the page. So check the page height property